# How to bind gridview in a textbox and How calculate the total value in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview, shopping-cart

I am currently working on a project for shopping cart. My program will display a grid view after I have retrieved from the database.

I hit an error when I want to retrieve from Quantity with a text box and a total value of the price.

I tried to use eval but there is an error stating the server tag is not well formed.

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advanced.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Cart" runat="server" EmptyDataText="There is nothing in your shopping cart." CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" ShowFooter="True" GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="ID" DataField="productID" />  
                <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Name" DataField="productName" /> 
                <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Model" DataField="Model" />
                <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Price (each)" DataFormatString="{0:c}" DataField="Price"/> 
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">            
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseQuantity" Width="40" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("Quantity") %>"></asp:TextBox> 
                </ItemTemplate>        
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">            
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <% String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToInt16(<%# Eval("Quantity") %>) * Convert.ToInt16(<%# Eval("price") %>) ))  %>
                    </ItemTemplate>        
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove Item">            
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox id="Remove" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>        
                </asp:TemplateField>        
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here the code behind:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string a = Session["customer_Username"].ToString();

        List<cart> allCart = new List<cart>();

        allCart = cBLL.getUsername(a);

        gv_Cart.DataSource = allCart;
        gv_Cart.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tag was indeed not well formed. Here is a better version:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToInt16(Eval("Quantity")) * Convert.ToInt16(Eval("price")) %>
```

Note that it uses just section of `<% %>`, there is no inner server tags here. These tags are not supposed to be nested.

**Update.** As for the Quantity field you just need to correct your quotes. Use single quotes for attribute value and double quotes for Eval:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but I also hit error on the Purchase Quantity saying the tag is not well formed. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure where you are saying the error is.. but this looks wrong..

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">            
        <ItemTemplate>
            <% String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToInt16(<%# Eval("Quantity") %>) * Convert.ToInt16(<%# Eval("price") %>) ))  %>
        </ItemTemplate>        
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Should be something like this I would imagine..

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">            
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="lblOne" runant="server" text="<% String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToInt16(<%# Eval("Quantity") %>) * Convert.ToInt16(<%# Eval("price") %>) ))  %>"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>        
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">            
    <ItemTemplate>
          <%# String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToInt16(Eval("Quantity")) * Convert.ToInt16(Eval("price")) %>
   </ItemTemplate>        
  </asp:TemplateField>
```